# Is making a NSManagedObject a delegate a good practice?

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, nsmanagedobject

task details:

I'm developing an app that communicates with 1-30 hardware devices simultaneously, each device has it's own tcp connection.

Therefore I created an entity "hardwareObject" which shall represent some properties of that device, e.g. value1 and value2.

I created a connection handler class which I defined as a transient attribute of my "hardwareObject" entity. On UI changes the core data object is modified and the core data object itself tells it's connection to send changes of value1 or value2.

I want to inform an instance of "hardwareObject" when new data arrived via a delegate method, therefore it's a delegate of it's attribute.

I'm wondering if making a NSManagedObject a delegate of s.th. is a good practice?

Might that cause any problems regarding faulting or other core data related things?
Or should I better create a sharedInstance master connection handler object which takes care of each of the connection handlers and talk to my core data objects only on demand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a totally valid design. NSManagedObjects may be managed by their (managed object) context, but if you retain an NSManagedObject it will remain valid, and you're free to implement any special business logic in that class or make it a delegate. In fact, one of the resounds that Core Data allows you to subclass NSManagedObject is such that you can do these things.

Just make sure to unregister your class as the delegate if you need to delete the object from the context.

Comment: you suggest then to retain the delegate property instead of assigning it in order to keep the NSManagedObject subclass "alive"?

Comment: Whenever you have an `obj <-> delegate` relationship you need to make sure both ends (obj and delegate) remain valid as long as both have a relationship to one another. The *classic* approach is one where the delegate retains the obj (e.g. the view controller retains the table view) and the obj has a weak reference to the delegate (table view has a weak ref to the view controller). You can use this, too, but then you need to make sure that the managed object unsets itself as the delegate when it goes away (inside `-didTurnIntoFault`). Otherwise you'll have dangling pointers.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bad idea. Delegates need to exist for at least as long as the object they are a delegate for, and you don't have control over the lifecycle of managed objects - this is taken care of by the context.

As you mention in your question, faulting could also be an issue - any state information could disappear at any point, again, out of your control.

In addition, this sounds like quite a serious violation of MVC, if that concerns you.

Comment: How is this a violation of MVC? observing state changes, as a matter of fact, is an integral part of MVC. What is KVC? The first paragraph mentions model change observers: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html.

Comment: Are you talking about KVC? I'm talking about MVC. They're two completely different things.

Comment: My MVC point was that the OP would effectively be making a model object part of the controller.

Comment: When I read it I thought he was suggesting the reverse: have a model object notify a delegate when something had changed in the model, which is pretty standard MVC. I would agree, having a model object monitoring something else doesn't make much sense.

Comment: My point on KVC was if model objects being observable was wrong, that would not exist.